# PHP - How to find if a date is between 2 dates

Tags: php, date, pdo

I get some datas with dates from a database :

```
$data['my_date'])
```

Type is date : YYYY-MM-DD

I would like to make with PHP a condition to found if $data['my_date']) is between 2 dates like :

```
if ($data['my_date'] >= 2009-01-01 && $data['my_date'] <= 2009-12-31) {
    $datas = '5';
}
else {
    $datas = 1;
}
```

It doesn't work as expected, the condition is not verified. What should i do ?

Comment: You need to quote your dates, or else they are being interpreted as integer operations (`2009-01-01 == 2007`)

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós you should post your answer ("need to quote your dates") because it was the solution. I'm confused to have made this mistake.

Comment: @SébastienGicquel posted as answer. And don't worry, we all have had silly unexplainable mistakes in the past ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no literal syntax for dates, you should enclose them in quotes and treat them as strings. If you are using the `YYYY-MM-DD` format, then it is sortable alphabetically, and your current method should work.

```
if ($data['my_date'] >= '2009-01-01' && $data['my_date'] <= '2009-12-31') {
    $datas = '5';
}
else {
    $datas = 1;
}
```

If you don't quote your dates, you are doing integer operations:

```
$data['my_date'] >= 2009-01-01  ====> $data['my_date'] >= 2007
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert all dates by [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to timestamp and then compare them.

```
strtotime($data['my_date']) >= strtotime('2009-01-01')...
```

Comment: no need to call `strtotime` if all dates are `YYYY-MM-DD` (this format is sortable alphabetically/numerically).

Comment: @Carlos: there is no guarantee, be on safe side is better

Comment: @RaheelHasan Thanks, really easy, i've tried with strtotime() before but it didn't work because i forgot the quote ' ' around the date strtotime('2009-01-01')

Answer (score 1):

You use either `strtotime()` or `mktime()` to convert your dates into timestamp, then compare it.